# WebClient UploadStringTaskAsync fails with no exception

Tags: c#, async-await, webclient

I am calling UploadStringTaskAsync on a restful Web API 2 post method I wrote and it is failing with no exceptions.  If I change the call to be UploadString, it works as expected.  I've tried a number of different approaches.  With UploadStringTaskAsync attempt Fiddler does show the post being issued but with a content-length mismatch (see below).   I am running this call from a class library included in a test console app.  .Net 4.5.2  So far just running in debug mode from VS 2015.  here's my code:

```
private async Task PostLoggingItem(SmgLoggingItem loggingItem)
    {
        try
        {
            //using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            //{
            //WebClient client = new WebClient();

                const string authToken = "mytoken";

                loggingItem.AuthToken = Encryptor.GenerateSecurityToken(authToken);

                client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                //client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                //client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user","mypwd","mydom");

                // set content type to JSon
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

                var jsonItem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loggingItem);
            var response = await client.UploadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebLogAPI"]), jsonItem);

            //string response = client.UploadString(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMGWebLogAPI"]), "POST", jsonItem);

            string result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response);

                if (result != "ok")
                {
                    await SMTPSendEmailAsync.SendEmail("brownp@spectrummg.com", "logging failed WebAPI call",
                        "Error return from WebAPI call in PostLoggingItem");
                }
                return;

            //}
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await SMTPSendEmailAsync.SendEmail("brownp@spectrummg.com", "logging failed WebAPI call",
                "Exception in PostLoggingItem" + e.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

You can see where I have commented out the working UploadString call.  Also, I have a theory problem related to "lifetime" of the WebClient object, so played around with creating it in the method (see commented using), but now create it with the object instantiation to which method PostLoggingItem belongs.

here's fiddler:
[image]

I'd sure like to know why the Async does not work.  Also, I have used aync methods and awaits all the way up the call tree - to no avail.

Comment: Well I found the problem.  I was testing this method from a simple console app that was exiting before the web call could even be created!